# How to set a variable name as same as the column name it is operated on?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been trying to set the column name in which the following function is operated to the output the function produces.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(A)) {
    if (class(A[[i]]) == "numeric")
    a1<-(c(mean(A[[i]]),  median(A[[i]]), min(A[[i]]), max(A[[i]])))
    a2<- as.data.frame(a1,row.names= c("mean", "median", "minimum", "maximum"))
}
```

I need the column name of `A[[i]]` instead of `a2` which I have specified.
I tried `names(A)[i]` and there is no progress.

Comment: i have tried that one. the problem here is  i need to perform different functions on  each column of dataframe and save them as individual .csv files. I have factors, numeric, date types in my columns.

Comment: my bad... should have detailed the question.

Comment: it worked.. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop over the columns of 'A' using `lapply` and get the `mean`, `median`, `min` and `max` for the `numeric` columns.  `Filter` the NULL elements out and `cbind` the `list` elements to get the output.

```
res <- do.call(cbind,Filter(length,lapply(A, function(x)
           if(is.numeric(x))
            c(mean=mean(x), median=median(x),minimum= min(x), maximum=max(x)))))
res
#                col1      col3 col4
#mean     0.007221454 0.5245963  1.3
#median   0.134166961 0.4970547  1.5
#minimum -0.848370044 0.1480248  0.0
#maximum  0.847460017 0.9691335  2.0
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
A <- data.frame(col1= rnorm(10), col2=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, 
           replace=TRUE), col3=runif(10), col4= sample(0:5, 10, replace=TRUE))
```